# Is it ok to have two stepper motors right next to each other?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, interference, proximity

Would there be any issues having two nema 23 stepper motors laying right next to each other, facing opposite ways (see image)? 48v, 4amps.

[image]

Comment: possible overheating issue

Comment: Motors require air flow over the housing for adequate cooling. Look for manufacturer recommendations. Also look at everything else that effects losses and cooling such as load, duty cycle, ambient temperature, and altitude. Some spare capacity in one category may let you get away with violating the limits in another.